The problem with derivation of an equation in a many-body book
In the corrected version (14 January 2016) of the book "Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics: An Introduction (Oxford Graduate Texts)" chapter 8, for the following time dependent Schrowdinger equation (Eq. (8.13))  $$[i\partial_t-H_0(r)-V(r)]\psi(r,t)=0      $$ the non-interacting Green's function is defined by (Eq. (8.14b)) $$[i\partial_t-H_0(r)-V(r)]G(rt,r't')=\delta(r-r')\delta(t-t').$$ It says: if
the wavefunction is known at some time $t'$, then the wavefunction at a later time $t$ is
given by (Eq. (8.21)): $$\psi(r,t)=\int dr'G(rt,r't')\psi(r',t')$$
where the integral is only over $r'$ while the $t'$ remains without summation. I would like to know whether this equation is correct or there is a typo?

Yeah it's almost certainly a typo, the integral should include $t'$ and $r'$, or else the formula wouldn't make sense. Should probably be $G(r,t,r',t')$ too.

Thanks, author also says Eq. (8.21) can be checked by inserting in Eq. (8.13) and using Eq. (8.14b). By using this we obtain
$[i\partial_t – H_0 (r)- V(r)]\psi (r,t)=\delta(t-t’) \psi (r,t’)=0$  because $t>t’$. But if it were a typo and we insert the correct version of Eq. (8.21) as $\psi(r,t)=\int dr’ dt’ G(rt,r’t’) \psi (r’,t’)$ into the Schrodinger equation (8.13) we would have: $[i\partial_t – H_0 (r)- V(r)]\psi (r,t)=\psi(r,t)$
which denies the Schrodinger equation!
